# Borders in CSS fall on top of each other for a table

Tags: css, border, css-tables

I have the following CSS for my table

```
#currency_table
{
    th { background-color: red; width: 119px; height: 45px;border-right: 1px solid #cfcfcf; border-left: 1px solid #ededed;  }
    th:first-of-type { width: 131px; }
    th:last-of-type { width:45px;} 
}
```

problem is that the border-right and border-left fall on top of each other so I do not see two border lines, but rather just one! I made sure that the width is large enough so that it is not a size issue.

What is wrong here?!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you get and what you want and also your HTML?

Answer (score 0):

See `border-collapse` and `border-spacing`: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#borders. If that doesn't help, you may want to post your actual HTML.